# Can I properly make password-protected 7z archives secure?

Tags: passwords, file-encryption, zip

After reading the question and answers of [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33410/can-password-protected-zip-files-be-broken-without-brute-force/35817) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35818/are-password-protected-zip-files-secure), I left with an overall impression from the last one that zips were considered not safe and insecure way of sharing data.

I still think password-protected compressed files can be made secure. So let me get this straight with this very

**Specific scenario**

- You're using the `7z` command, version 9 or above, in a Linux machine. Not `zip`. Not `rar`.
- Correct me if I'm wrong, but 7z uses AES-256 by default when password protected, no matter if the archive format is going to be `.zip` or `.7z`
- You want to create a self-extract file `archive.exe` from directory `dir1` and want all filenames contents and names and all headers to be encrypted, so you run

  `7z a -mhe=on -psecretpassword -sfx archive.exe dir1`
- The password used was very strong, assume entropy enough
- You securely shared the password with the file's intended recipient. Only you two know the password
- You also securely share the archive's `SHA1` hash
- You now make this file available for the person to download

**I say that**

- The person can extract this archive even in a Windows machine without any program just with knowledge of the password
- The names of the files in encrypted directory `dir1` cannot be read if you don't know the password
- The archive cannot be tampered with file substitution because filenames and headers were also encrypted
- Any tempering would be noticed if the person checked the `SHA1` after downloading
- In terms of confidentiality of file names and contents, this is as secure as compressing the directory with anything (zip, rar, tar.gz) and applying `openssl aes-256-cbc` on it
- The self-extraction adds no vulnerability, and if it did, simply removing the `-sfx` or changing it to `-t7z` would fix it, though in this case the person would need 7-zip to extract it

**Correct or not?**

Comment: **Yes, correct.**

Comment: One caveat: not all zip client tools support all decryption methods, so you can't assume everyone will have the tools for opening the file you send them.

Comment: WARNING: The 7zip program on windows often leaves encrypted files in a plain-text state in temporary files. While 7zip is a great protocol, the program itself is incredibly insecure and refuses to fix the issue, so please don't use that one and be aware that other programs may have similar problems

Comment: @BT or anyone else - is this still the case for 7zip? Do you have a source for this claim?

Comment: @PedroA The owner of the project doesn't think its a problem for some reason. Its very irresponsible that Igor has knowingly left this gaping security hole in 7zip for years, getting near a decade now. https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/1448/

Comment: @BT PedroA That bug report thread touched on the problem -- encrypted archives on removable media are potentially used in two different use cases.  One is to carry data between trusted computers, passing through an untrusted environment where your disks may be searched (such as network security).  This one actually makes a modicum of sense and requires that unencrypted copies are never placed on the removable media, but on a system drive in the trusted coomputer is OK.  The other (bringing an on-the-go work environment to an untrusted kiosk) is just insecure no matter what 7-zip does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question: Is a self-extracting archive encrypted with a perfect implementation of AES, using a key with sufficient entropy secure against an eavesdropper or active man-in-the-middle, if a cryptographic hash of the archive and the key are transmitted over a separate channel which is assumed to be secure?

Yes.

Some of these assumptions may not hold in the real world, though.

Examining the first assumption, there's a relevant question on this forum from almost a year ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470378/how-key-derivation-and-key-verification-functions-are-implemented-of-a-7-zip-arc

According to the discussion there, 7z uses a strong password-based key derivation function, and AES in CBC mode (which is fine, because we're assuming a SHA1 hash of the archive gets verified before decryption is attempted; which will stop padding oracle attacks).

However, the previous discussion also highlights a lack of documentation, and hard-to-read code in 7z. I'm not aware of any substantial cryptanalysis being done on 7z; so in using it, you're ultimately putting your trust in its developer to have gotten all the crypto implementation correct.

Answer (score 3):

> - The archive cannot be tampered with file substitution because filenames and headers were also encrypted
> - The self-extraction adds no vulnerability

This is incorrect: if the expected use case is by running the self-extracting archive, any attacker able to tamper with the .exe file may also modify the self-extraction code to change the decompressed files in any way he sees fit. (Of course, he can also do much more, like logging the password or installing a backdoor)

So if you're in a situation where tampering is even remotely possible, self-extracting archives are a very bad idea.

Comment: I believe this assumes the attacker can also manipulate the executable in a way that allows it to have the same SHA1 hash (which has been securely transferred) as the original executable... right? -- of course, the recipient would have to actually compute and compare the hash before running the executable...